# Why do I have to use the model keyword in emberjs in the template?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I created a template in my emberjs project as a partial which worked fine for one of the pages in my ember application. When I tried to reuse the partial in another page I needed to use the `model` keyword to get it to work in both pages.

Sample handlebars template I have

```
{{SomeProperty.NestedProperty}}
```

became

```
{{model.SomeProperty.NestedProperty}}
```

Why did I need to change from the first one to the second one?

I have routes similar to this:

```
this.resource("foretak", {path: "/foretak"}, function() {
    this.route('opprett', { path: "/nytt/:org_nr" });
    this.route('detaljer', { path: "/:id" });
});
```

The first route (opprett) used the template where I didn't have to specify `model` but for the second route I needed to prefix everything to get it to work for both routes.

Routes:

```
SFag.ForetakOpprettRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return params.org_nr;
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var opprettForetak = SFag.OpprettForetak.get(model);
        controller.set('model', opprettForetak);
    }
});

SFag.ForetakDetaljerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return params.id;
    },
    setupController: function(controller, id) {
        var foretak = SFag.Foretak.get(id);
        controller.set('model', foretak);
    }
});
```

Controller is empty. The method `SFag.Foretak.get` and `SFag.OpprettForetak.get` are getting the same type of data but from different endpoints.

Also if I do write ´{{SomeProperty}}´ I will see ´[Object object]´ printed in both cases, so it is bound to something.

Comment: how does your template parent controller / route look like?

Comment: your update shows the router map, I asked for the controller/route definitions, this is interesting because it will show how you are setting the model for those routes

Comment: @intuitivepixel, One more update. I've tried to reproduce a smaller sample but haven't succeeded.